# How to upgrade libfuse-dev from 2.9.2 to 2.9.4 Ubuntu Server 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I have been trying all day to upgrade my version of libfuse-dev 2.9.2 to libfuse 2.9.4. I am on Ubuntu Server 14.04 (headless) But it seems that it has a TON of dependencies which need to be upgraded first. Libfuse sent me to libfuse2 to update to 2.9.4, then to libc6 etc... I can't upgrade anything without needing to upgrade another dependency. This is getting annoying, and I need to get libfuse-dev to 2.9.4. I have tried forcing installs, installing dependencies one by one, using gdebi, but nothing works. I need help. Please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, since you are on server, not desktop you need to install all the major packages needed by typing on terminal

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

that should install needed packages up to libc6-dev. If it doesn't work, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

I also recommend you to remove your current version by typing

```
sudo apt-get remove libfuse-dev
```

Second, go to `packages.ubuntu.com/it/wily/libfuse-dev` (or any other you find)

it has `libfuse-dev 2.9.4-1` - then download `libfuse2`, `libpcre3`, `libpcrecpp0`, `libpcre3-dev`, `libselinux1`, `libsepol1`, `libsepol1-dev` ,`libselinux1-dev` (install these respectively in their order)

Third open terminal then change directory to where you downloaded them

e.g `cd /home/ubuntu/download`

Fourth, to install type in terminal, for example,

```
sudo dpkg -i libfuse2_2.9.4-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

then proceed to installing the others. Dont forget to install them in the above order, `libfuse2` then `libpcre3`...

Fifth, finally install `libfuse-dev 2.9.4-1` you downloaded first

And that should do it

Comment: Why i386 and why you are sure, that the Wily package will work in Trusty?

Comment: i386 is just for example, this wily package worked for me on 12.04.3 desktop 32-bit. But first i removed the installed library libfuse-dev